# CSS transformation reinitialized after form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I m facing an issue when I click on my search button.

When my form is first loaded and I type a word inside the input, we can see the label inside it moving at the bottom of the input thanks to some translateY.

But when I submit my form, it s like the css is being “cancelled” and going back to what it was originally by putting back the labels inside the input.

Also after the submit, it is not the same radio button which is being checked than before the submit.

Is there a way to say “leave css as it even after submitting the form” ?

Thanks

Below are my html / css and JS

```js
$(document).ready(
  function() {
    debugger;

    $('.form').find('input:not([type="radio"])').on('keyup blur focus',
      function(e) {
        console.log('this is my script');
        var $this = $(this),
          label = $this.prev('label');

        if (e.type === 'keyup') {
          if ($this.val() === '') {
            label.removeClass('active highlight');
          } else {
            label.addClass('active highlight');
          }
        } else if (e.type === 'blur') {
          if ($this.val() === '') {
            label.removeClass('active highlight');
          } else {
            label.removeClass('highlight');
          }
        } else if (e.type === 'focus') {

          if ($this.val() === '') {
            label.removeClass('highlight');
          } else if ($this.val() !== '') {
            label.addClass('highlight');
          }
        }

      });
  }
);
```

```css
*,
   *:before,
   *:after {
     box-sizing: border-box;
   }
   html {
     overflow-y: scroll;
   }
   body {
     background: #c1bdba;
     font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
   }
   .form {
     background: rgba(19, 35, 47, 0.9);
     padding: 40px;
     max-width: 70%;
     margin: 40px auto;
     border-radius: 4px;
     box-shadow: 0 4px 10px 4px rgba(19, 35, 47, 0.3);
   }
   h1 {
     text-align: center;
     color: #ffffff;
     font-weight: 300;
     margin: 0 0 40px;
   }
   label {
     position: absolute;
     -webkit-transform: translateY(6px);
     transform: translateY(6px);
     left: 13px;
     color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
     -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease;
     transition: all 0.25s ease;
     -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
     pointer-events: none;
     font-size: 18px;
   }
   label .req {
     margin: 2px;
     color: #57b7ff;
   }
   label.active {
     transform: translateY(40px);
     animation: forwards;
     left: 2px;
     font-size: 14px;
   }
   label.active .req {
     opacity: 0;
   }
   label.highlight {
     color: #ffffff;
   }
   input:not([type=radio]),
   textarea {
     font-size: 22px;
     display: block;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     padding: 5px 10px;
     background: none;
     background-image: none;
     border: 1px solid #a0b3b0;
     color: #ffffff;
     border-radius: 0;
     -webkit-transition: border-color .25s ease, box-shadow .25s ease;
     transition: border-color .25s ease, box-shadow .25s ease;
   }
   input:focus,
   textarea:focus {
     outline: 0;
     border-color: #ede741;
   }
   textarea {
     border: 2px solid #a0b3b0;
     resize: vertical;
   }
   .field-wrap {
     position: relative;
     margin-bottom: 10px;
   }
   .top-row:after {
     content: "";
     display: table;
     clear: both;
   }
   .top-row > div {
     float: left;
     width: 23%;
     margin-right: 2%;
   }
   .top-row > div:last-child {
     margin: 0;
   }
   .button {
     border: 0;
     outline: none;
     border-radius: 0;
     padding: 15px 0;
     margin-bottom: 10px;
     font-size: 2rem;
     font-weight: 300;
     letter-spacing: .1em;
     background: #57b7ff;
     color: #ffffff;
     -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
     transition: all 0.5s ease;
     -webkit-appearance: none;
   }
   .button:hover,
   .button:focus {
     background: #179b77;
   }
   .button-block {
     display: block;
     width: 30%;
   }
   .forgot {
     margin-top: -20px;
     text-align: right;
   }
   fieldset {
     margin-bottom: 30px;
     border: 0.5px solid #57b7ff;
   }
   legend {
     font-size: 1.5rem;
     color: #57b7ff;
   }
   /*.searchtype{
      margin-left: 8px;
      margin-top: 20px;
    }*/
   input[type=radio] {
     margin-top: 10px;
     margin-right: -5px;
     padding: 0px;
   }
   label.radio {
     cursor: pointer;
     overflow: visible;
     position: relative;
     margin-bottom: 10px;
     margin-right: 25px;
   }
   label.radio:before {
     background: #57b7ff;
     content: '';
     position: absolute;
     top: 0px;
     left: -30px;
     width: 20px;
     height: 20px;
     border-radius: 100%;
   }
   label.radio:after {
     opacity: 0;
     content: '';
     position: absolute;
     width: 0.5em;
     height: 0.25em;
     background: transparent;
     top: 7.0px;
     left: -25px;
     border: 3px solid ghostwhite;
     border-top: none;
     border-right: none;
     -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
     -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
     -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
     -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
     transform: rotate(-45deg);
   }
   input[type=radio]:checked + label:after {
     opacity: 1;
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form">
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="wrapperAll">
      <h1>Wrapper Testing Tool</h1>
      <form id="wrapperForm" method="POST" runat="server" action="WrapperTestingTool.aspx">

        <fieldset>
          <legend>Connection Info</legend>
          <div class="top-row">
            <div class="field-wrap">
              <label>
                Organization ID<span class="req">*</span>
              </label>
              <input id="inputOrgId" type="text" required autocomplete="off" runat="server" />
            </div>

            <div class="field-wrap">
              <label>
                User Name<span class="req">*</span>
              </label>
              <input id="inputUserName" type="text" required autocomplete="off" runat="server" />
            </div>

            <div class="field-wrap">
              <label>
                Password<span class="req">*</span>
              </label>
              <input id="inputPassword" type="password" required autocomplete="off" runat="server" />
            </div>

            <div class="field-wrap">
              <label>
                Source<span class="req">*</span>
              </label>
              <input id="inputSource" type="text" required autocomplete="off" runat="server" />
            </div>
          </div>

        </fieldset>

        <fieldset>
          <legend>Client Details</legend>
          <div class="top-row">
            <div class="field-wrap">
              <label>
                Name<span class="req">*</span>
              </label>
              <input id="inputClientName" type="text" required autocomplete="off" runat="server" />
            </div>

            <div class="field-wrap">
              <label>
                Client ID<span class="req">*</span>
              </label>
              <input id="inputClientId" type="text" required autocomplete="off" runat="server" />
            </div>


            <input type="radio" value="None" id="radioIndividual" name="account" checked runat="server" />
            <label for="radioOne" class="radio">Individual</label>
            <input type="radio" value="None" id="radioOrg" name="account" runat="server" />
            <label for="radioTwo" class="radio">Organization</label>
            <input type="radio" value="None" id="radioElement" name="account" runat="server" />
            <label for="radioThree" class="radio">Specific Element</label>
        </fieldset>

        <button type="submit" class="button button-block" />Search</button>

        <div>
          <textarea rows="6" cols="150" id="searchResults">
            <%=t his.ResultLookup %>
          </textarea>
        </div>

      </form>

      </div>



    </div>
    <!-- tab-content -->

  </div>
  <!-- /form -->
```

Comment: Perhaps you mean to submit the form using Ajax?

Answer (score 0):

You need to prevent the form refresh upon submisson:

Jquery:

```
$("#wrapperForm").on("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("wrapperForm").onsubmit = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: and ajax to send to server

Comment: I don't think he uses ajax

Comment: Thanks no refresh but now it is not calling my function in my C# code. I have a check: "if (Page.IsPostBack) { myMethod()"  but since i added the preventDefault i m not hitting the "if". I want to click on the search button which would execute a method in the code behind (without any refhres of the form). I tried to call the method by using <% myMethod() %> but then it was executed when the page load, it is not being executed on the click of the btn (i added an addeventlistener to my button injavascript. How to execute a method in C# from an html button without executing a refresh of the form?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how is it in asp.net (I've never used it), but if you are not using ajax and if you want to keep everything as it was then you have to reuse data, you've sent through form. That means you have to check if something was already sent through the same form. Your page does reload and that is why your form refreshes. In php you get that data through `$_POST`, `$_GET` or `$_REQUEST` arrays. I hope that helps (in a way)